# MYSQL add 1 to max value in substring_index

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add 1 to my max field value in mysql query:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(0001-14-A,'-',1)) AS prefix;
```

RESULT:

```
prefix
------
 0001
```

However when i do like this:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(0001-14-A,'-',1)) + 1 AS prefix;
```

RESULT:

```
prefix
------
 2
```

How to remain the value format to ****? Please advise.

Comment: If you _ever_ find yourself having to manipulate sub-columnar data, your schema is wrong. It won't scale well and you'll find yourself having to perform what I like to call "SQL gymnastics" to achieve something that would be much simpler if you separated the attributes correctly.

Comment: Is it always 4 digits or could it be more?  And what is `MAX()` being used for in this case?

Comment: @sgeddes yes,the format must be 4 digits, and actually the value itself i retrieve from a table, but to make it clear in this example, i put it as a value. yeah, i should remove the max.will edit that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are missing single quotes:

```
 SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('0001-14-A', '-', 1)) + 1 AS prefix
```

When you add one to the value, it is converted to an integer.  To get a string back, you need to pad it:

```
 SELECT LPAD(MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('0001-14-A', '-', 1)) + 1, 4, '0') AS prefix
```

Comment: It might be worth adding a note that if `foo` is longer than 4 characters, `LPAD(foo,4,'0')` will return only the first four characters of `foo`. I mention that because it appears you may be intending to cycle through `'0002'`,`'0003'`, ... and eventually, you'll be at `'9999'` +1 and the LPAD(,4) is going to return `1000`.

Comment: @spencer7593 -- I had the same question to OP.  A slight variation would be to use `LPAD(foo,LENGTH(foo),'0')`